# Is using methods that return instances an antipattern?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

In b4 sorry for creating such a vage topic but I'll try to be as concise as possible.
I'm trying to improve an object oriented design for a php package I made. I have an **Api** class that represents en Http external API. This class has methods like **get**, **post**, **delete** etc... and encapsulates some response retrieval or json decoding. This class recieves a GuzzleHttp client as it's constructor parameter to do so.

Then I created some classes for the many endpoint categories the API has like **Sale**, **User**, etc...
An example method you can find in a class like **Sale** would be `recent()` and it's code would do something like:
`$this->api->get('recent-sales-endpoint.json')`. This would require injecting **API** into **Sale** as a dependency and this way I could write its unit tests and so as I always do.

Now if I try to act as a user that installed my library and wants to get the recent sales, I have to do things like:

```php
$api = new Api($client);
$sale = new Sale($api);
$recentSales = $sale->recent();
$car = new Car($api);
$newCars = $car->getNew();
```

So I was wondering if this was is an improvement or an antipattern for making my package more pleasant to use.

On my **API** class constructor I create instances for every category class like.

```php
private $client;
private $car;
private $sale;
public function __construct(Client $client)
{
    $this->client = $client;
    $this->car = new Car($this);
    $this->sale = new Sale($this);
}
```

And then I can create acesssor methods like:

```php
public function sale()
{
    return $this->sale
}
```

So for the package user to retrieve the data now it would be:

```php
$api = new Api($client);
$recentSales = $api->sale()->recent();
$newCars = $api->car()->getNew();
```

Which of these two ways do you think is the most correct way? Also I thought I could initialize these instances when being queried the first time instead of doing it in the constructor, but I don't know if I'm complicating the design too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is correct and incorrect way of doing this. I feel that your option 2 feels nice to use:

```
$api = new Api($client);
$recentSales = $api->sale()->recent();
```

It's up to you how you want the API of your package to look like. I think it's a good idea to make it somewhat flexible so that developers using your package can pick the option that works best for their use-case.

You can always look at how other packages do it, I like this libary from stripe:
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/tree/master/lib

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php